# parse image src with simple html dom

Tags: php, html-parsing

im trying to get src image from this link: https://www.scribd.com/book/348571030/The-Alice-Network-A-Novel

this what ive don but no luck

```
<?php

 include('simple_html_dom.php');

 $html = file_get_html('https://www.scribd.com/book/348571030/The-Alice-Network-A-Novel');

 $list = $html->find('div[class="class="auto__base_component auto__shared_react_document_image react_document_image""]',0);

 $list_array = $list->find('img');

 $list_array2['thumb']  = $list_array->find('img.loaded', 0)->src;

 for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($list_array2); $i++ ){
  echo $list_array2[$i]->plaintext;
  echo "<br>";
 }

?>
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I get it done using the php class `DOMDocument` by getting all images in that page and then you can select what you want:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.scribd.com/book/348571030/The-Alice-Network-A-Novel');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo $image->getAttribute('src') . "\n";
}
```

I gues if you are looking for the cover img, it's the third image so get as below:

```
echo $images[2]->getAttribute('src') . "\n";
```

Comment: Check my update for how to get all images in the page.

Comment: thanks man its working but it gives me 3 link and i want just to parse the img with the class="loaded" can you please modify it for me

Comment: Inside the loop `for` i mentioned, add an if statement to check if `$image->getAttribute('class')` is equal to 'loaded' then you got what you need.

Comment: i already did it with preg_match and its working on localhost but not on real server (bluehost)

Comment: i guess `class='loaded'` added dynamically so why at the runtime you will not find it. maybe you need to find another way to identify `img` tag.